# Запуск питон скрипт на сервере

Tags: python

Я разработал ВК Бот на языке Питон на Windows. То есть этот бот работает только при включенным состоянии компьютера и только после запуска скрипта, но не будет работать, если выключить компьютер. Как исправить ситуацию?

> Я пробовал pythonanywhere.com, но, к сожалению, там лимит на 100 CPU
>   SECOND, то есть время работы сервера ограничено.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы программа работала на выключенном компьютере? Это к Дэвиду Блэйну с его особой магией...

Comment: любой VPS в помощь

Comment: Можно развернуть это на Heroku

Comment: @Alban Heroku усыпляет инстансы, к которым нет обращений.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, лайфхак: можно прикрутить какой-нибудь внешний мониторинг, который будет периодически слать запросы на сервис.

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте питон на удаленом хостинге. Компютер либо выключен и не работает, либо включен и работает, третьего не дано.

Comment: Либо есть индус, но это опционально :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобиться хостинг в таком случае. Рекомендую [pythonanywhere](http://pythonanywhere.com), так как других **бесплатных** хостингов, полностью предназначенных для python, ты не сможешь найти (ну или я чего то не знаю в своей жизни).

Comment: Danil_super_2, автор вопроса же прокомментировал, почему ему не подходит pythonanywhere.com. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Ну я акцентировал, что других бесплатных хостингов не найти.